# XML for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

Fairly new to android, I am working on a page, and I want my texts and image to be placed perfectly on the centre of the page.

something like this:

[image: How I want my result to be.]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mealsthatheals.emfitech.com.About">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/Appname" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/version"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Appname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/version"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Appname"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/webLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20px"
        android:text="@string/www.emfitech.com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/copyright"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:id="@+id/copywright"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/webLink"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="73dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/all_rights"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/reserve"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/copywright"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/version" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I want the outcome to be all centred in the middle.

Comment: Try putting android:gravity = "center"  on everything you want centered.

Comment: The content in your image is not centered. Anyway you want LinearLayout with `gravity:"center_horizontal"`, does not work in relativelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it like this by using android:layout_centerHorizontal="true".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_about"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Appname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/version"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Appname"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/version"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="10sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/version"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/webLink"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20px"
    android:text="@string/www.emfitech.com"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/copywright"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webLink"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="@string/copyright"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/reserve"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/copywright"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/all_rights"
    android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for `ImageView` and anchor other elements to it.

Comment: The Image is not centered, only horizontally

Answer (score 0):

For better perfomance in this case (I insist on the fact that this is not always true) and to achieve your goal, I would switch the top container from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout with a gravity = center.

But if you want to keep the RelativeLayout, each element should specify

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Like you did in the first Text View.
Don't forget that the way you will achieve centering will depend on the container layout you are using. Not on the type of view inside this layout.